# Merge 2 Tables from different Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hypothetically I want to merge 2 tables from different databases into one table, which includes all the data from the 2 tables:

[image]

The result would look like something like this:

[image]

Aren't the entries in the result table redundant, because there are 2 entries with Porsche and VW? Or can I just add the values in the column 'stock' because the column 'Mark' is explicit?

Comment: Please tag your question with RDBMS you use

Comment: Why don't you group by `Mark`?

Comment: Are the databases in the same SQL Server instance?

Comment: It's entirely possible to do what you're saying in your result, and what you're suggesting in your text. What do you *need* to do? The entries aren't obviously redundant since they come from apparently different transactions. On the other hand, adding them together may not make sense (for example, if one of the tables is `cars` and the other is `parts`, then `Stock` has no useful meaning across both tables). Without a clear indication of what you're trying to do, it's hard to give you an answer that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to create database link to another database here is the example on how to create database link http://psoug.org/definition/create_database_link.htm
   after creating your select statement from another database should look: `select * from tableA@"database_link_name"`
2. Then you need to use MERGE statement to push data from another database so the merge statement should look something like this.
3. you can read about merge statement here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606

   ```
   merge into result_table res
   using (select mark, stock, some_unique_id
            from result_table res2
          union all
          select mark, stock, some_unique_id
            from tableA@"database_link_name") diff
   on (res.some_unique_id = diff.some_unique_id )
   when matched then
     update set res.mark = diff.mark, 
                  res.stock = diff.stock
   when not matched then
     insert
       (res.mark, 
            res.stock, 
            res.some_unique_id)
     values
       (diff.mark, 
            diff.stock, 
            diff.some_unique_id);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Mark) AS new_ID, Mark, SUM(Stock) AS Stock
FROM 
(
SELECT Mark,Stock FROM Database1.dbo.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Mark,Stock FROM Database2.dbo.table2
) RESULT 
GROUP BY Mark
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Mark, Stock, row_number() over(order by Mark desc) from table1 
union all
Select Mark, Stock, row_number() over(order by Mark desc) from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

regardless of the data redundancy, you could use `union all` clause to achieve this. Like:

> `Select * From tableA
>      UNION ALL
>      Select * From tanleB`

Make sure the total number of columns and datatype should be matched between each

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use fully qualified table names as the tables are in different databases

```
SELECT
 Mark
,Stock
FROM Database1.dbo.table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
 Mark
,Stock
FROM Database2.dbo.table2
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are 2 live databases and you would need to constantly include rows from the 2 databases into your new database consider writing the table in your 3rd database as a view rather.

This way you can also add a column specifying which system the datarow is coming from. Summing the values is an option, however if you ever have a query regarding a incorrect summed value how would you know which system is the culprit?